# How to check all check boxes when a parent checkbox is checked in nested checkbox structure?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi all i have an complex checkbox structure which looks like this

```
<div class="accordian-group">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentcheckbox" value""/>
        <ul>
         <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/>
            <ul>
               <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
               <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/>
                    <ul>
                      <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
                    </u>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentcheckbox" value""/>
        <ul>
         <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/>
            <ul>
               <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
               <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/>
                    <ul>
                      <li> <input type="checkbox" value""/></li>
                    </u>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is when a parent check box is checked all the checkboxes in side that div should be checked and if i check one by one all inside child boxes of a parent checkbox the parentcheckbox should be checked

and i have a add button in my page on click of add button if the parent categorie is checked and all the childrens of that div are checked i should get all the values how can i do this can any one help me in solving this or can guide me through this

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uf7D/)

```
// Whenever the parent checkbox is checked/unchecked
$(".parentcheckbox").change(function() {
    // save state of parent
    c = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(this).parent().find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        // set state of siblings
        $(this).attr('checked', c);
    });
});

// Update parent checkbox based on children
$("input[type=checkbox]:not('.parentcheckbox')").change(function() {
    if ($(this).closest("div").find("input[type=checkbox]:not('.parentcheckbox')").not(':checked').length < 1) {
        $(this).closest("div").find(".parentcheckbox").attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest("div").find(".parentcheckbox").attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.siblings` doesn't go recursively down the tree does it? It would only check... well my siblings. Which I don't believe is the author's use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) return; // do nothing if not checking
  var li = $(this).closest('li');

  // check all children 
  $('li input[type="checkbox"]', li).prop('checked', true);

  // see if all siblings are checked
  var all = true;
  li.siblings().find('>input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) all = false;
  });
  if (all) {
    // check parent checkbox
    $(this).closest('ul').closest(':has(>input)')
          .find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ezeroy/3/)